# Omitted Part of Yonah?

Tags: tanach, text, yonah-jonah-book-of

I had heard once that there was an omitted/deleted part of Sefer Yonah after Hashem's response to Yonah about the kikayon. Is this true? Is there a source for this idea?

Comment: Any idea where or what context you heard this? Why a concern for The book of Jonah vs. any other book? An answer to some of these questions may assist the research.

Comment: What do you mean by omitted/deleted?

Comment: I was unable to find such a section in the Septuagint, Josephus or in the apocrypha.

Answer (score 2):

["Let My Nation be Warned"](http://www.feldheim.com/let-my-nation-be-warned.html) explains that this is why we throw in three pesukim from Michah at the end of the Haftarah. Although this is the end of the Sefer, those three pesukim were Yonah's response.

Comment: Doesn't Michah live after Yonah?

Comment: Maybe. Not sure. But does that preclude them from saying the same thing?

Answer (score -2):

There's a midrash that Yonah responds to God, effectively -- "I submit. You do with the world as You see fit."

Comment: Where is this Midrash recorded?

Comment: What does this have to do with a deleted part of the book?